# Concurrent object pool whose products' lifetime is fully controlled by the smart pointer(s) containing the object

Tags: c++, multithreading, object-pooling

I wanna design a Concurrent object pool in C++, possible prototype as:

```
template<std::size_t OBJ_SIZE>
class Pool {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void new(std::shared_ptr<T> & product);
    // more details...
};
```

- Once object(product) is returned, its lifetime is fully controlled by the smart pointer(s) containing the object.
- Pool may be used by multiple threads.

How do we automatically reclaim the object/memory after user is done with it?

My idea is to have a delete() method in pool, which is called in product's destructor.

Is there a better design? e.g. a way where product classes are less coupled with Pool (note it's a generic pool). Any idea is welcomed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements. Are you saying that you want the lifetime of the allocated object to be controlled by the lifetime of the unrelated shared_ptr that is passed in?

Comment: @RichardHodges, the shared_ptr is used to contain the returned object, and take control of its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to return a shared_pointer with custom deleter. Deleter will know how to delete the object using pool's deallocate() method. This is standard approach to this problem.